# How to change nominal attribute value order in WEKA GUI?

Tags: user-interface, weka, variable-types

I have 2 data sets for train and test with weka. They both having same amount of attributes and same type data type for variables (numeric or nominal) .But they are not compatible with each other  because the order of nominal values is different

```
ex - Training set

     Occupation
  1   Doctor     40%
  2   Engineer   40%
  3   Teacher    20%

   Test set

  1   Engineer     40%
  2   doctor       40%
  3   Teacher      20%
```

So both sets are incompatible. My question is how to change these distinct value order to make them compatible?

Answer (score 2):

It looks a bit like a data pre-processing issue.  I am quite curious as to how the training and testing data ended up looking like this!

If you would like to change the nominal values, you could use [RenameNominalValues](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/RenameNominalValues.html) to rename the labels of your data.  One possible method is to apply this to your testing data:

[image: RenameNominalValues Sample]

This solution assumes that you are dealing with a Nominal attribute, that it is your last attribute and they are labelled as shown in the valueReplacements field.

Failing this, depending on the amount of cases, you could edit the values manually or use your favourite spreadsheet to replace the values.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: it cannot be rename nominal values, it needs changing the order, not the labels

Answer (score 0):

Use "SwapValues" under unsupervised > attribute